# javascript prettier formats objects on several lines

Tags: javascript, prettier

I run Prettier in my VSC-editor and I've had a problem with the formatting of objects for a while now. The problem is that it will always format the objects on several lines, even when there is room for the entire object on one line.

**Input**

```
let map = {
  0: { x: 0,  y: -1 }, 
  1: { x: 1,  y: 0 },  
  2: { x: 0,  y: 1 }, 
  3: { x: -1, y: 0 }  
};
```

**Output**

```
let map = {
  0: {
    x: 0,
    y: -1
  },
  1: {
    x: 1,
    y: 0
  },
  2: {
    x: 0,
    y: 1
  },
  3: {
    x: -1,
    y: 0
  }
};
```

It also does this with imports:

**Input**

```
import { Foo } from 'Bar';
```

**Output**

```
import {
  Foo
} from 'Bar';
```

These are my current rules:

```
editor.formatOnSave": true,
"prettier.singleQuote": true,
"prettier.printWidth": 80,
"prettier.bracketSpacing": false,
"prettier.proseWrap": "always",
"prettier.trailingComma": "all"
```

Are there any ways to prevent this behavior, preferably permanently?

Comment: Did you try to set proseWrap to one of the other values (never, preserve). Looks like the only sensible one for me

Comment: @bambam Tried both, and neither of them did anything